# How can I remove an image from a button?

Tags: java, image, button, javafx, graphics

I am working on a project where I set an image from a button like this:

```
`p2cardTableSlot00.setGraphic(new ImageView(player2Table.getGameCards().get(0).getCardImage()));`
```

My question is how can I remove the picture of
`player2Table.getGameCards().get(1);` and get a simple custom button image back?

Code snippet:

```
public void p2cardTableSlot00Handler(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    player2Table = new CardDeck(new ArrayList<>());
    player2Table.getGameCards().add(getPlayer2hand().getGameCards().get(0));
    player2Table.getGameCards().add(getPlayer2hand().getGameCards().get(1));

    if(p2card00selected)
    {
        p2card00selected = false;
    }else
    {
        if(p2cardTableSlot00selected)
        {
            p2cardTableSlot00selected = false;
        }else
        {

            p2cardTableSlot00.setGraphic(new ImageView(player2Table.getGameCards().get(0).getCardImage()));


            p2cardTableSlot00selected = true;
        }
        p2card00.setGraphic(new ImageView(player2hand.getGameCards().get(1).getCardImage()));
        p2card00selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to remove an image from a button ?

Comment: yes, I would like to take the image from the button and reset it, which is shown by default

Comment: Just set graphics to null `setGraphic(null)`

Comment: Thank you , it works;)